# Rails Help, How to create user_id on 2 tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, controller, nested

I have the following

User model

```
has_many :investment_stocks
has_many :investment_prices
```

Investment_stock model

```
belongs_to :user
has_many :investment_prices, dependent: :destroy
accepts_nested_attributes_for :investment_prices
```

Investment_price model

```
belongs_to :investment_stock, optional: true
belongs_to :user, optional: true
```

But I am having difficulty in adding in a nested form to create on investment_stock and investment_price tables a user_id

investment_stocks controller

```
def new
@investment_stock = InvestmentStock.new
@investment_stock.investment_prices.build
end

def create
@investment_stock= InvestmentStock.new(investment_stock_params)
@investment_stock["user_id"]= current_user.id
```

How do I make it such that the user_id appears on both the stock and price tables on my investment_stocks controller?

Comment: Can we take a look at your `views/investment_stocks/_form.html.(whatever)` partial ?

Comment: <%= form_for @investment_ut, url:investment_uts_path do |f| %>

    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :name %><br />
      <%= f.text_field :name, autofocus: true %>
    </div>
    <div class="actions">
      <%= f.submit "Submit" %>
    </div>

Crap I have no idea how to format in this forum

Comment: An an option next time just add an 'Update 1' section and add the code. Here you can just write 'updated question'. Answering below

Answer (score 0):

In your `create` action, assign `user_id` by setting the user object itelf:

```
@investment_stock.user = User.find(current_user.id)
```

After that, when you call `@investment_stock.save()`, you will get both the tables with the `user_id` set.

Comment: But the user_id does not appear on the investment_price table. It does appear on the stocks table though

Answer (score 0):

follow up your question how to create user_id on 2 tables if these two tables do not have user_id you can create with these step below

create migration file

```
rails generate migration AddUserIDToInvestmentStock
```

open your migration files and just add one line **add_reference** as follow

```
class AddUserIDToInvestmentStock < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
 def change
   add_reference :investment_stocks, :user, index: true
     # this will create user_id in table investment_stocks
     # although I named user field since the type is reference
     # rails will create user_id
 end
end
```

for second table I believe you can repeat step above since it same steps only different table

- if you want to learn more about nested form, railcast [episode 196](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1) and [episode 197](http://railscasts.com/episodes/197-nested-model-form-part-2) is good basic to learn

Comment: Actually both my tables do have the user_id column, but when I try to create a stock, it appears on both tables but the user_id only gets updated on the stock table but not the prices table

Answer (score 0):

So I guess there can be several approaches to what you're attempting to achieve here. 
One can be, setting those 'un-editable' attributes on the `#new` action.

```
def new
  @investment_stock = InvestmentStock.new(user_id: current_user.id)
  @investment_stock.investment_prices.build(user_id: current_user.id)
end
```

For this to work end-to-end you need to have a hidden field in the form that will maintain the value in the params hash.

```
- form_for @investement_stock, url: investment_stocks_url(@investement_stock) do |f|
 = f.hidden_field :_method, :post
 = f.hidden_field :user_id
 = f.text_field :whatever_attribute

 = f.fields_for :investment_prices, @investment_prices do |ip_form| 
   = ip_form.hidden_field :user_id
```

In the controller you should have request params like:

```
{
  controller: "InvestmentStocks",
  action: "create",
  ....
  # whatever other attributes coming from the form
  user_id: {some-user-id},
  investment_prices_attributes: {
    "0" => {
       "user_id" => {some-user-id}
       ...
       # whatever other attributes coming from the form
    }
  }
}
```

In this option you'd be exposing the user ID in the HTML - so anyone can inspect it and put another id in order to attempt malicious actions. In order to avoid this always check that the current user ID equals the one being sent in the form, else reject the request.

Another way is catching the params before you actually attempt to persist the record. Meaning you can tap into the request params and set whatever you want there

```
def create
  @investment_stock = InvestmentStock.new(investment_stock_params)
  if @investment_stock.save
    ...
  else
    ...
  end
end

private 
def investment_stock_params
  investment_stock_params = params[:investment_stocks].tap |stocks_attributes|
     stocks_attributes["investment_prices_attributes"]["user_id"] = current_user.id
  end
end
```

Note that I made an example without considering strong parameters nor any other potential patterns you might have in your current implementation. So let's call this a very rails 3 ('old' fashion) solution. But is not that different from how it would be done in rails 5 these days.

In any case, do read about nested forms. As @widjajayd commented above, RailsCasts will greatly help in understanding this rails feature.

Comment: Will this work with other nested params? Like replace all the user_id with other params like name?

Comment: Within the tap you can manipulate anything. Set this according to your needs and let's see if it's what you need or not...